# How do you create a custom edge renderer in SigmaJS so that edges have a bigger hover/click area than their size?

Tags: sigma.js

I am using SigmaJS v2 and every object is rendered using WebGL which I am new to. I have seen examples of custom node rendering by creating new WebGL programs. However, I do not see any examples of custom edge rendering. Specifically, I would like to know what I need to change or manipulate in a WebGL program to adjust the edge's hover/click area size independent of the edge's size.

I would like to try a lot of other things like making the edges transparent too! But any help just starting with the hover and click area size would be greatly appreciated.

I have copied and pasted the "normal" shaders and programs into my app and referenced them so I have the scaffolding for custom rendering set up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.